# Guessing Game Number Issue

Tags: c#

Before I get down-voted for the extensive code, I feel it's necessary for a solution to present itself.

I've made alterations to the program's code from the help previously presented, but I still seem to be falling into the problem that the random number `number` is either not being properly compared (I've had examples where `number` is '5' and the user's guess is '5', but I'm still getting a comment that  "You're quite far off! Try again." meaning it's falling into `else if (userinputcalc > 4 | userinputcalc < 10)...`

So, at this stage the issue seems to lie within the comparison of `number` and the `userinput`, leading to confusing output messages.

I'm probably missing something obvious here, despite being sure it's around the loop of comparing `number` and `userinput` but I've been looking at this code and seeing nothing.

Any help is greatly appreciated, as always.

```
    public void GuessingGame()
        {
            string username; // Will be the user's chosen name for program interaction
            int guessesleft = 0;// Stands for the number of guesses left (out of 3)
            int spaceaway = 0; // Space from the guess and the random number, if not correct guess
            int roundcount = 1; //Started at 1 for the sake of the user interface - aesthetics
            int number = 0; // Current value of the random number
            int userinput = 0; //User input is the guess the user makes during the guessing game
            int userinputcalc = 0;// calculation of guess and random number, when added to spaceaway calculation
            int answersright = 0; // Number of times the user guessed the number correctly

            Random rndm = new Random(); // Initialises a new class of random, which'll be used to simulate the random number

            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Guessing Game!");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Please press any button to continue.");
            Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("What's your name?");
            username = (Console.ReadLine());
//If you're wondering at all, the "You must guess what it is inthree tries." is intentional, since it was showing double-spaced in the command prompt
            Console.WriteLine("Well, " + username + ", I am thinking of a number from 1 to 10. You must guess what it is inthree tries.");
            Console.WriteLine("");


            {
               do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Round" + roundcount); //Displays the which round (out of 10) to the user


                    guessesleft = 3; //The remaining guesses left for the user

                    do
                    {
                        number = rndm.Next(10) + 1; // int number is set to a random number between 1 and 10

                        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a guess:");
                        userinput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        guessesleft = guessesleft - 1;


                        if (userinput == number)
                        {
                            //Below,  once you've guessed right, you will have this message displayed in the console
                            Console.WriteLine("You guessed " + number + " *RIGHT*!");
                            answersright = answersright + 1;
                            guessesleft = 0;// No point need to guess further on something you've guessed correctly - saves correct answer value exploit
                        }

                        else if (userinput < 1 || userinput > 10) // If user's guess is less than 1 or more than 10, then out of range. Counts as a guess.
                        {           
                            Console.WriteLine("You guessed " + userinput + "! and it was incorrect!");
                            Console.WriteLine("This is outside of the range of numbers between 1-10 ");

                        }


                        else if  (userinput != number) // while the user's guess does not equal the number
                        {
                            {
                                // userinputcalc = Math.Abs(number - userinput);  
                                //Left out as I was getting abnormal run-time outputs and the math showed up wrong.
                                //(Example: RND No. = 5 Userinput = 5 Output: "Incorrect" "Hot")

                                spaceaway = (number - userinput); // Works out how far from the random no. the user's guess is.
                                // If user guesses 6 and random no. is 5, answer will be -1 this makes the value +ve and allows output to be shown without error
                                if (spaceaway < 0)
                                {
                                    spaceaway = (spaceaway * -1);
                                    userinputcalc = spaceaway;
                                }

                                else if (spaceaway > 0)
                                {
                                    userinputcalc = spaceaway;
                                }

                            }

                            {
                                if (userinputcalc < 2)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("You guessed " + userinput + "! and it was wrong!");
                                    Console.WriteLine("Hot");
                                }

                                else if
                                     (userinputcalc < 3)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("You guessed " + userinput + "! and it was wrong!");
                                    Console.WriteLine("Warm");
                                }

                                else if
                                    (userinputcalc < 4)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("You guessed " + userinput + "! and it was wrong!");
                                    Console.WriteLine("Cold");
                                }

                                else if (userinputcalc > 4 | userinputcalc < 10)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("You guessed " + userinput + "! and it was wrong!");
                                    Console.WriteLine("You're quite far off! Try again.");
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    } while (guessesleft > 0);

                    Console.WriteLine("");
                    Console.WriteLine("The number was, "+number+"!");
                    Console.WriteLine("");

                    roundcount = roundcount + 1;

                } while (roundcount < 11);

                Console.WriteLine("Well, " + username + ". " +  "You guessed correctly, " + answersright + " times!");


                }


            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please post relevant code, not _everything_...

Comment: Posting a huge chunk of code doesn't help us much. You need to describe exactly what you want to happen, exactly what is going wrong, and please try to reduce your code to only what is really critical to your problem.

Comment: One observation: if the user guesses within one, two or three values of the given number, it will always enter the first branch of the if statement and show the "cold" message.  Once it displays this message it will jump out of the if statement and increase the round count.  You should probably rearrange your if statement so that the most unlikely match is checked for first.

Comment: This is because one, two and three are all less than four...

Comment: I think you've now deleted too much information and now its unclear where the user input comes in and what the problem is you are trying to solve, take 5 - 10 minutes to structure your code/question so it is clear what the outcome is, and where you think the problem lies

Comment: I hope that helps now. Specifically, this section ` userinputcalc = /*Math.Abs -- No, wrong! Bad...*/(number - userinput);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I think theres quite a few issues here (some are off topic but *definitely* worth mentioning)..

1. I wouldn't advise using while loops to check for specific inputs

   For example:
    Instead of `roundCount != 11` use `roundCount < 11`

   Then there is less chance of forever getting stuck in a loop
2. You should declare Random outside of your loops otherwise you run the risk of just getting the same numbers ("randomly")
3. You reset the number to a new number after every guess so the user doesn't have a chance to guess the right number

With all this being said, I think the Math.Abs was correct if you are trying to find the distance away from the number.. I wouldnt use less than two though as that would mean only numbers that are 1 away from the answer are "hot"

Note: Answer is based off question revision #5

---

**Update**

Doesn't seem like you were far off but you still reset the number every loop

```
 number = rndm.Next(10) + 1;  //Insert here
 do
 {
      //Displays the which round (out of 10) to the user 
      Console.WriteLine("Round" + roundcount); 
      guessesleft = 3; //The remaining guesses left for the user
      do
      {
          // Remove this -- number = rndm.Next(10) + 1;
```

Comment: Sayse, I've made alterations, as per the useful help but I still seem to be facing this issue at hand.

Comment: @Jackie - gimme 5 - 10 minutes I'll see what I can do

Comment: Huzzah! I put it here and it works! `do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Round" + roundcount); //Displays the which round (out of 10) to the user
                    number = rndm.Next(10) + 1; // int number is set to a random number between 1 and 10
                    
                    guessesleft = 3; //The remaining guesses left for the user

                    do`

Comment: @Jackie - hehe, you know your program better than I would in 5 minutes :) hope answer makes sense

Comment: I appreciate your help greatly, since the changes you advised and then helping with the final piece of the puzzle made it all come together. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want,please try it:

```
        static int guessesleft;
        static Random ran = new Random();
        static int MagicNumber;
        static string UserInput;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo ci = new ConsoleKeyInfo();
            do
            {
                guessesleft = 3;
                UserInput = "";
                Console.Clear();
                string username;
                int guesscount = 1;
                Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Jackie's Guessing Game!");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Please press any button to continue.");
                Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine("What's your name?");
                username = (Console.ReadLine());
                //If you're wondering at all, the "You must guess what it is inthree tries." is intentional, since it was showing double-spaced in the command prompt
                Console.WriteLine("Well, " + username + ", I am thinking of a number from 1 to 10. You must guess what it is inthree tries.");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                MagicNumber = ran.Next(1, 11);

                do
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Please insert your " + guesscount++ + "º guess!");
                    UserInput = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
                    if (UserInput == MagicNumber.ToString())
                        break;

                    if (Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(UserInput) - MagicNumber) < 2)
                        Console.WriteLine("Hot!!");
                    else if(Math.Abs(Convert.ToInt32(UserInput) - MagicNumber) < 3)
                        Console.WriteLine("Warm!!");

                    Console.WriteLine("No luck , you have " + --guessesleft + "º guesses left!");
                    Console.WriteLine();

                } while (guesscount < 4);

                if (guesscount == 4)
                    Console.WriteLine("Sorry " + username + " no more tries,you lost!");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Congratulations your guess with number " + UserInput + " is correct,the number was " + MagicNumber);

                Console.WriteLine("Press Q to quit or Enter to Play again!");
                ci = Console.ReadKey();
            } while (ci.Key != ConsoleKey.Q);  

        }
```